# Can not run ionic project using command ionic server

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Using these versions of Ionic, Cordova, and Node.js

Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 <br>(C:\Users\yymal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)<br>
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2<br>
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0<br>
```

Cordova:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)<br>
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0<br>
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 7 other plugins)
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)<br>
npm    : 6.4.1<br>
OS     : Windows 10<br>
```

When I type ionic serve in the command line, I get the following error:

> [app-scripts] '"E:\uQuestfinal\node_modules.bin\ionic-app-scripts"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [app-scripts] operable program or batch file.
>
> [ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
>
> The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[app-scripts] Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.

Do you get that in the error message? It worked after I ran that command.

Answer (score 0):

please change your ionic version to 3 from 4